# Xamarin Forms: view coordinates null on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, view, coordinates

In Xamarin Forms if i create a simple view, like a `BoxView` and I place into an `AbsoluteLayout` with the proper `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds` and `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags`, then if I try to retrieve the box coordinates with `box.X; box.Y, box.Width, box.Height` in Android they result null, 0,0,-1,-1. In iOS they are returned correctly.

Code example

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    BoxView box;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        box = new BoxView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(box, new Rectangle(0.6, 0.6, 0.25, 0.25));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(box, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

        absolutelayout.Children.Add(box);

        Console.WriteLine($"Box coordinates: {box.X} {box.Y} {box.Width} {box.Height}");
        //IN ANDROID (galaxy s9 emulator): "Box coordinates: 0 0 -1 -1"
        //IN IOS (iPhone 11 emulator): "Box coordinates: 186 403 104 224"

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot get the x, y because the element is not drawn on the screen yet. If you can put a delay like Task.Delay (2000), you will see the x, y. But it's not solution.

Comment: @sermet it still doesn't work, keep returning 0 and -1 values, its odd because in iOS works even without using any delay.

Comment: Try getting the co-ordinates on a button click.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar doing that it works, but in my project i need them when the app loads

Comment: It is possible that this is a case of how pages render themselves per platform.  You might have to do something like this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22561/page-loaded-event

Comment: Though I don't know if the ChildAdded event is fired when the page adds its elements from the xaml or not, but it would be interesting to see if you can add that event handler on the absolute layout it self

Comment: Knowing your UI requirement will help. What is your exact UI requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to overriding the `OnSizeAllocated` method :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

            box = new BoxView
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            };
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(box, new Rectangle(0.6, 0.6, 0.25, 0.25));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(box, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

            absolutelayout.Children.Add(box);
            box.SizeChanged += Box_SizeChanged;
    }

 protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        //get the box's location
        Console.WriteLine($"Box coordinates:{box.X} {box.Y} {box.Width} {box.Height}");

    }
```

or add `SizeChanged` event to your box :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

            box = new BoxView
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            };
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(box, new Rectangle(0.6, 0.6, 0.25, 0.25));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(box, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            absolutelayout.Children.Add(box);
            box.SizeChanged += Box_SizeChanged;

    }

private void Box_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you could get the box's location here
        Console.WriteLine($"Box coordinates:{box.X} {box.Y} {box.Width} {box.Height}");
    }
```